# AS3 How to apply Glow Filters when GPU rendering for AIR for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, filter, bitmap, gpu

So I have been making an application using AIR for Android, and up until this point I've been using CPU Rendering (because I never knew that was an option I could/should change). The app itself has lots of objects with Glow Filters, and several of them are Dynamic Text that change based on player input. I also have some animations that I want running in the background for aesthetic purposes. Here is where my issue lies:

On CPU rendering, everything works great, except the animation running in the background causes pretty heavy lag.

On GPU rendering, the animations and everything run smooth as butter, but all of the Glow Filters don't render.

For GPU, I've read that I can make static glow objects into Bitmaps/PNGs and add them back onto the timeline, which would work perfectly for everything besides the Dynamic Text. I've also read that there is a workaround, converting Display Objects into Bitmaps (don't really know how to do that) and then adding the Glow Filter as Bitmap Data (no idea how to do that either). I would hope that would work with Dynamic Text, but have no idea of how to implement it to test it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Thank you! :)

Comment: Read https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html about **draw(...)** and **applyFilter(...)** methods.